# How can I solve "ValueError: Cannot convert to Excel"? (Using Python & openpyxl)?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, valueerror

I am scraping a price from a website using lxml and I'd like to insert that price into an existing Excel file using openpyxl. When I run the code, I get the error:

> ValueError: Cannot convert ['$364'] to Excel

('$364' is the scraped price). How do I fix this? It appears that line 11 of code: `sheet['A1'] = price` is the problem. My entire code is below:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://www.randomlengths.com/Woodwire/RL-Lbr-Pnl/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
price = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main-frame"]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/strong/text()')
print(price)

import openpyxl
xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/noah.merkousko/randomlengthslumber.xlsx')
sheet = xfile.get_sheet_by_name('Framing Lumber')
sheet['A1'] = price
xfile.save('random lengths lumber test.xls')
```

Answer (score 1):

"ValueError: Cannot convert ['$364'] to Excel" is telling you the error. You are trying to place a list `['$364']` into a cell that contains values. You can fix this by either indexing when you put it in Excel or indexing when it's parsed from online.

Option 1:

```
price = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main-frame"]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/strong/text()')[0] # index at 0
```

Option 2:

```
sheet['A1'] = price[0] # index when you put into Excel
```

It is worth noting that this may introduce an `IndexValue` error if the site is altered and the value is no longer located at `'//*[@id="main-frame"]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/strong/text()'`, but otherwise should solve your problem

Comment: Hi @Reedinationer, thanks for the help here. It looks like if I combine both the options you laid out into my code, it solves the ValueError. However, it only puts "$" in the excel file. It does not put the full "$364" price into the excel file. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Scooter You should not combine them. Using one will get the first item in the **list** (the string '$364'). Using the other option in conjunction with that will get the first item in the string (the '$' character). I meant you have two ways to fix your problem, and you should pick **one** of the options.

Comment: when I only use one of the options you laid out, I still get the ValueError. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error as an exception.

```
try:
    sheet['A1'] = price
except ValueError:
    print("Handling the error case")
```

Comment: Hi @Jack, thanks for the help. Looks like that solved the ValueError, but it does not put any data into the excel file. Any idea why that might be happening?