# How do I populate (update) an excel workbook with data from a django model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, openpyxl

I populated a Django model with a pandas dataframe.

In order to do this is had I used the `to_dict()` function in order for `JSONField()` Django model to accept the data.

This works well. Now what I am trying to do is to update an excel file with these data.

So I am accessing the data in the Django model and trying to use `openpyxl` to populate an excel with the new data data.

However I am running into problems as I am getting the error saying that it cannot convert to excel.

Is there anyway around this?

**My model:**

```
class myvalues(models.Model):
    items_list = models.JSONField()
```

**Function that’s trying to populate excel:**

```py
    values_to_go_into_excel_obtained_from_model = myvalues.objects.values_list(“items_list”, flat=True)
    path = file_for_download.my_file.path
    wb = load_workbook(path)
    ws = wb["Sheet1"]
    pd.read_excel(path, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name="Sheet1")
    
    for row, v in enumerate(values_to_go_into_excel_obtained_from_model, 2):
        ws.cell(row, 4, v)
    
    wb.save(path)
```

Any ideas why I am getting the error? Basically what I'm trying to do is:

```
Step 1: pandas df -> Django model of type Json
Step 2: Access Django model values
Step 3: put values from Django model into excel file
```

I have step 1 and 2 but cannot get step 3.

Comment: Your Question is not that much clear. Not sure `models.JSONField()` it should be like `jsonfield.JSONField()` it seems you tried to put some part of code manually. Also `load_workbook` and rest code indicate you are trying to update an excel with the addition of one new cell. Please share a snapshot of the error you are getting and some sample data of your `myvalues` model.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please share example data and expected output. At what line is the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save one particular json into the excel file

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary_from_query)

df.to_excel(filepath)
```

Or if you need to add multiple jsons, add them to a list then use that list to initialize the dataframe

```py
ds = []
for ...:      # your loop
    ds += [d] # where d is one of the dicts

df = pd.DataFrame(ds)

df.to_excel(filepath)
```

In your case I think the dictionaries are already in a list. Therefore you can just use the second method.

Answer (score 0):

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/55131749/1021819, it seems possible that you are trying to write a list to a cell (which is a way to provoke the error you are seeing).

So you need to loop over the list:

```py
values_to_go_into_excel_obtained_from_model = myvalues.objects.values_list(“items_list”, flat=True)
path = file_for_download.my_file.path
wb = load_workbook(path)
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
# pd.read_excel(path, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name="Sheet1") # not required!
    
for row, v in enumerate(values_to_go_into_excel_obtained_from_model, 2):
    for row_val, i_row_val in enumerate(row):
        ws.cell(row_val, 4+i_row_val, v)
    
wb.save(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your openpyxl version.

openpyxl 3.0.2 has a bug in generating Excel pages. This may be the issue